# CDataProvider column length

Tags: php, yii, dataprovider

I have grid

```
<?php $this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbGridView',array(
    'id'=>'products-grid',
    'htmlOptions'=>array('class'=>'grid-view table-striped',),
    'dataProvider'=>$model->search(),
    'columns'=>$columns,
)); ?>
```

$model->search()

```
return new CActiveDataProvider($this, array(
            'criteria' => $criteria,
            'pagination' => array('pageSize' => 50)
        ));
```

And I need to limit length of every column. For example, if column 1 has value

> "Hello World"

and config variable for first column is 7, then I need to render

> "Hello W..."

I think, that i can solve my problem with behaviours, am I right? Please, help me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[CDataColumn value option](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDataColumn#value-detail) helps me

```
foreach($columns as &$column)
{
    if($column['name'] == 'number')
    {
         $column['value'] = 'strlen($data->number) > 14 ? substr($data->number, 0, 14)."..." : $data->number';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your search function to this..not sure if its the fastest

```
public function search(){
$returnarray = array();
$dataset =  new CActiveDataProvider($this, array(
            'criteria' => $criteria,
            'pagination' => array('pageSize' => 50)
        ));
    foreach($dataset as $ds){
        $returnarray['your_table_index'] = (strlen($ds->your_element) > 8) ? substr($ds->your_element,0,7).'...' : $ds->your_element;
    }
   return $returnarray;
}
```

Comment: Yes, i understand, how to cut string. But where can i write this code? I have only `$this->widget('...');`

Comment: Can you provide me the link of which widget you are using...may be it has some configurations set

Comment: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CGridView base widget for TbGridView, there is no config for length

Comment: Whats that `$model->search()` do ? ..i think thats your data ..use `substr`..from there